# Fit a line with LOESS in R

Tags: r, loess

I have a data set with some points in it and want to fit a line on it. I tried it with the `loess` function. Unfortunately I get very strange results. See the plot bellow. I expect a line that goes more through the points and over the whole plot. How can I achieve that? 
[image: plot]

How to reproduce it:

Download the dataset from https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud32tbptyvjsnp4/data.R?dl=1 (only two kb) and use this code:

```
load(url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud32tbptyvjsnp4/data.R?dl=1'))
lw1 = loess(y ~ x,data=data)
plot(y ~ x, data=data,pch=19,cex=0.1)
lines(data$y,lw1$fitted,col="blue",lwd=3)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to download the data file.  It did download, but I could not read it.  What format is it in?  Could you upload an ASCII DOS text file?  Maybe I am doing something wrong.  Maybe I need to have DropBox installed on my machine to read the downloaded file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You've plotted fitted values against `y` instead of against `x`. Also, you will need to order the x values before plotting a line. Try this:

```
lw1 <- loess(y ~ x,data=data)
plot(y ~ x, data=data,pch=19,cex=0.1)
j <- order(data$x)
lines(data$x[j],lw1$fitted[j],col="red",lwd=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

May be is to late, but you have options with ggplot (and dplyr). First if you want only plot a loess line over points, you can try:

```
library(ggplot2)
load(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud32tbptyvjsnp4/data.R?dl=1"))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

[image: Loess line with <code>ggplot::geom_smooth()</code>]

Other way, is by `predict()` function using a loess fit. For instance I used dplyr functions to add predictions to new column called `"loess"`:

```
  library(dplyr)
  data %>%
  mutate(loess = predict(loess(y ~ x, data = data))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color = "grey50") +
  geom_line(aes(y = loess))
```

[image: Loess line with <code>predict()</code> and <code>geom_line()</code>]

**Update**: Added line of code to load the example data provided 
**Update2**: Correction on `geom_smoot()` function name acoording @phi comment

Comment: Commenting on an old post, but I thought I'd point out that there is a typo in the code. "geom_smoth" should be "geom_smooth". Since typos in code makes the code unable to run, it is worth pointing out.

Comment: Why doesn't we get the same curves between `ggplot` and `loess`?

Comment: `geom_smooth()` predicts for a internal sequence generated for the entire range of `x`, while loess in the example predicts only for the unique `x` values existing in the dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the data are not available anymore, but an easier way how to fit a non-parametric line (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing or just a LOESS if you want) is to use following code:

```
scatter.smooth(y ~ x, span = 2/3, degree = 2)
```

Note that you can play with parameters `span` and `degree` to get arbitrary smoothness.

Comment: The data are back, thanks for the hint. Probably you can change your answer accordingly.