# Loess fit wrong in R, lines all over the place?

Tags: r, line, loess

I'm having a problem with Loess fit in R. I'm using the default iris dataset included with every R installation. However, when I try to make a loess line, it goes all over the place. The loess line for loess(y~x) is in red, and since I wanted to experiment and see if I was ordering x and y wrong, the line for loess(x~y) is in blue. As you can see, these lines are very clearly wrong. Why is this happening? I can't seem to fix it. Here is the code:

```
#ignore
library(lattice)
#cloud()

#CODE OF CONCERN BELOW
data <- iris
n<-150
x <- data$Petal.Length
y<-data$Petal.Width
plot(y ~ x)
loess_fit <- loess(y~x)
lines(x, predict(loess_fit), col = "blue")
```

Here is the picture of what I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: You need to order the points first. x <- sort(data$Petal.Length); 
y<-data$Petal.Width[order(data$Petal.Length)]

Comment: ... or order the variables in the lines function call . `lines(x[order(x)], predict(loess_fit)[order(x)], col = "blue")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit a line with LOESS in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337777/fit-a-line-with-loess-in-r) Also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007830/loess-line-not-plotting-correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to order the points before using loess.

```
x <- sort(data$Petal.Length)
y<-data$Petal.Width[order(data$Petal.Length)] 
plot(y ~ x)
loess_fit <- loess(y~x)
lines(x, predict(loess_fit), col = "blue")
```

[image: loess curve]